# Issue with image background and Fullpage.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, background

I am using fullpage.js and I am trying to add an image background to one of my slides, however when I do so the page 'skips' a section on its own.
My current css for the section is the following:

```
#slide1{background-image: url(https://github.com/antonettis/fullpage/raw/gh-pages/img/chess.jpg); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: auto 100%; }
```

I compared it to the fullpage.js demo, and if I copy it this is what my code should look like:

```
#slide1{background-image: url(https://github.com/antonettis/fullpage/raw/gh-pages/img/chess.jpg); background-size: cover; background-attachment: fixed; }
```

However when I do this the image completely disappears. [Here is the codepen](https://codepen.io/antonettis/pen/brEKgR). The image is on page 4, slide 1. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Working perfectly for me(page 3 slide 2): https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MvKXVP?editors=1100

Comment: It's not there in my HTML! It should be on the first slide of the fourth page...   <div class="horizontal-scrolling" id="slide1"><h1>page 4 slide 1</h1></div>. The slide1 div is the one with the CSS code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace css code with this:

```
.fp-section{
    background-image: url(https://github.com/antonettis/fullpage/raw/gh-pages/img/chess.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: auto 100%;
 }
```

Comment: I used #slide1: <div class="horizontal-scrolling" id="slide1"><h1>page 4 slide 1</h1></div>. Your option adds the background image to all the sections/slides, I only need one of them to be covered!